# Ignore FindBugs warning for field annotated by custom annotation

Tags: java, findbugs

Let's say we have a servlet with a field injected by OSGi container.

```
public class TestServlet extends GenericServlet {

    @Reference
    private Service service;

    // other stuff

}
```

Of course we use `service` in servlet methods and FindBugs complains that it's not safe to use instance fields in servlets. We can't make this field final. Is there any way to disable specific rule for fields annotated with custom annotation (`@Reference` in this case)? We don't want to pollute code with FindBugs-specific annotations.

Comment: Update your FindBugs, it shouldn't report a violation.

Comment: Ours is complaining about `@Rule`-annotated variables in JUnit tests not being used. Ideally, there would be a way to configure FindBugs/SpotBugs about specific annotations to be ignored.